# How to delete multiple records from SQL table

Tags: sql

I need to delete ~600 computer name`s from SQL table. All computers have unique name. I know that I can delete one by one, but it will take some time to delete 600 devices.

the question is - how can i seperate multiple computer name`s ?

To delete one by one I used:

```
select from [tablename]
where HostName = 'computername'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to

```
delete from [tablename]
 where hostname in ('name1', 'name2', ...);
```